# NSURLSession delegate and completionHandler

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using NSURLSession + NSURLDownloadTask with completionHandler:

```
[session downloadTaskWithURL:downloadURL completionHandler:^(NSURL *location, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error)
```

it works nice.

But when I want to track download in a progressBar I am running into problems.
I am trying to use NSURLSessionDownloadDelegate to track loading.
With the upper completionHandler it is never called?!

Using:

```
 NSURLSessionDownloadTask *downloadTask =
[session downloadTaskWithURL:downloadURL];
```

will call the delegates.

Is there any way to use completionHandler AND delegates? 
Or any other way to track download while using completionHandler?

Comment: Just use the delegate methods. What's the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To employ the `didWriteData` method of the `NSURLSessionDownloadDelegate`, you sadly have to use the rendition of `downloadTaskWithURL` without the `completionHandler` and then implement your own `URLSession:downloadTask:didFinishDownloadingToURL:` to perform those actions you otherwise would have done in the completion handler.

This is a little annoying (especially since the `NSURLSessionDownloadDelegate` is set at the session object), but it's how it works.

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSession_class/Introduction/Introduction.html):

> NSURLSession returns data in one of two ways, depending on the methods you call:
>
> - To a completion handler block that returns data to your app when a transfer finishes successfully or with an error.
> - By calling methods on your custom delegate as the data is received.

*One* of two ways. Either use the completion handler (if all you want is to be notified at the end) *or* use the delegate methods (if you want full information as you go). Not a problem. It's not like the delegate methods are hard to use or anything; it's probably just about always better to use them.